# Find the Maximum Products that BOTH Variables Can Have!

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, inequality

I would appreciate some help in solving this equation.

With $a,b,c  \in \mathbb{R}$ being fixed known values. How can I find the combination of $x$ and $y$ values that satisfy the relations below, and **maximise** (1) and (2) (by the way all variables and constants are greater than or equal to zero).

$$x + y = c, \; x<c, \; y<c, \; xa>c,(1) \; yb>c.(2)$$

**My approach to this:**

Let's assume I have found an $a$ and a $b$ such that  $(a * [ c - (c / b) ] ) >= (b * [c - (c / a) ])$

$( [ ( [ (a * [c - (c / b)] ) - c] / 2) + c] / a) = maximal\ x$

And so for $x + y = c$ to be true, $c - maximal\ x = maximal\ y $.

And, conversely, if I have found an $a$ and a $b$ such that  $(a * [ c - (c / b) ] ) < (b * [c - (c / a) ])$

$( [ ( [ (b * [c - (c / a)] ) - c] / 2) + c] / b) = maximal\ y$

and $c - maximal\ y = maximal\ x$

$Maximal\ x\ and\ y$ mean values of $x\ and\ y$ such that when they are multiplied by $a$ and $b$ respectively, the maximum values of $xa$ *and* $yb$ are achieved (whereas in (1) and (2) $xa$ may be larger than $yb$ while $yb\ =\ c$ and vice versa, $maximal\ xa$ and $maximal\ ya$ will both be greater than $c$ and $maximal\ xa\ <\ xa$, if the *original* $xa\ >\ c$ while $ya\ =\ c$ and vice versa ) .

Is there a method of calculating $x$ and $y$ such that $xa$ *and* $yb$ are maximised even more so than with my method, given that $a$ and $b$ are known?

Comment: By the way this is no homework, this is for a personal project of mine, and i'd really appreciate some insight.

Comment: Well, the first insight is that you really need to be clear about what you want. Exactly what expression are maximizing? In (1) and (2) (which you really ought to put on separate lines), all you state are restrictions on $x$ and $y$. You never give the expression you are trying to maximize.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I want BOTH to be maximised. I.e. the values of x and y which allow BOTH xa and yb to be the greatest possible, that is the values of x and y at which xa and yb can simultaneously be a their greatest (with x + y = c and the other inequalities being respected)

Comment: @PaulSinclair My reasoning was that this point occurred at the midpoint as if one of  xa and yb was greater than the midpoint of the greatest possible xa or yb ( with one of the other being equal to c ) then one of xa or yb would have to be less than xa or yb and beyond the midpoint in both positive and negative direction this divergences exists.

Comment: If $x + y = c$, then increasing $x$ decreases $y$, and vice versa. So there is no such thing as "maximizing both". Maybe you want to maximize $ax + by$? That is a well-defined concept.

Comment: @PaulSinclair "Is there a method of calculating x and y such that xa and yb are maximised even more so than with my method, given that a and b are known?"

Comment: @PaulSinclair " How can I find the combination of x and y values that satisfy the relations below, and maximise (1) and (2) "

Comment: @PaulSinclair There are values of x and y at which ax and by are maximised (meaning the greatest they can both be while respecting the other conditions). This is equivalent to "Maybe you want to maximize ax+by" provided the other conditions are respected.

Comment: No, it is NOT equivalent. "$ax$ and $by$" does not mean $ax + by$. If anyone ever told you differently, they were wrong. If you mean $ax + by$ then *please* say "maximize $ax + by$".

Comment: Since it has no critical points, the maximum of $ax+by$ will occur on the boundaries of the region. Since your boundaries are not part of the region (the inequalities are strict), there is no maximum that satisfies them. If you include the boundary ($x\le c, y \le c, ax \ge c, by \ge c$), then the maximum will occur at one of them (I.e. try the 4 values $x=c, x = c/a, x = 0, x = c - c/b$. In all cases $y = c - x$.)

Comment: @PaulSinclair You're right sorry, but I want ax and by to be the highest they can be while the other conditions are respected

Comment: But since increasing $ax$ *decreases* $by$, you are going to have to choose between them - to settle on a single quantity (such as $ax + by$, but there are other possibilities) that you want to maximize. *Until you do, your problem is ill-defined and no answer is possible.*

Comment: @PaulSinclair Indeed, and I choose which one (of either ax or by) according to the inequalities under 'my approach to this'. I was just wondering if this was a good basis to choose either of ax or by, as even in that choice I can get ax and by maximised.

Comment: I think you might want to be careful with your questions in the future, as this one isn't so clear.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have said in your comment on my answer that "a and b are always fixed known values", I'd like to give another answer.

First, lets observe the graph of $x+y=c$.  Allow c to be anything greater than $0$ and we see that it forms a simple linear equation with $x$ and $y$ intercepts at $c$.

Then we add the restrictions:$$x<c$$ $$y<c$$

From this, we get a little triangle in the top right quadrant.  Now note that we want:$$x*a>c$$ $$and$$ $$y*b>c$$

From my last attempted answer, I determined a function for $a$ and $b$.

$$\frac{b-1}{b^2}\ge\frac{a-1}{a^2}$$also$$a,b>1$$

I assume, then, that we only know $a$ $or$ $b$.  Because then we'd know both of them.

Particularly notice that if we knew what $b$ was, then $$a\to\infty$$ which is the most $a$ could be.

If we knew what $a$ was, then $b$ would have to be closer to 2, the absolute maximum of the function.  In math:$$|\frac{b-1}{b^2}-\frac 1 4|<|\frac{a-1}{a^2}-\frac 1 4|$$

However, this is only true if $a$ and $b$ were both on the same side of 2.  That is, if $a>2$, then $b>2$.  If $a<2$, then $b<2$.  Only then will the above equation give a result you want.

However, you must also note that you want $b_{max}$.  If $a<2$, you can still have $b>2$, but it will be harder to solve for.  If this is the case, then you want to use the following solution:$$\frac{b-1}{b^2}=\frac{a-1}{a^2}$$ $$a^2(b-1)=b^2(a-1)$$ $$a^2b-a^2=(a-1)b^2$$ $$0=(a-1)b^2-a^2b+a^2$$solve for $b$ using quadratic formula.$$b=\frac{a^2\pm\sqrt{a^4-4a^3+4a^2}}{2a-2}$$This will give you the solutions you want for $a$ and $b$.  Now, depending on if you want $a*x$ or $b*y$ to be maximized, you can correspondingly choose which variable to be larger.

Comment: Thanks alot! Question Answered.

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you have found $a$ and $b$ such that:

$(a∗[c−(c/b)])\ge(b∗[c−(c/a)])$

then:

$ac(1-\frac{1}{b})\ge bc(1-\frac{1}{a})$

and you may note that you can divide by c:

$a(1-\frac{1}{b})\ge b(1-\frac{1}{a})$

$a-\frac a b\ge b-\frac b a$

$ba^2-a^2\ge ab^2-b^2$

$(b-1)a^2\ge (a-1)b^2$

Recall that all variables are $\ge 0$ such that the signs don't switch.

$\frac{b-1}{b^2}\ge \frac{a-1}{a^2}$

note that I now have all b's and a's on opposite sides.

$f(b)\ge f(a)$

From here, I get:

$f(b)=f(a)$

$b=a$

or:

$f(b)>f(a)$

Note that $a, b$ must be greater than 1 because $ax>c$ and $x<c$.

If you look at the graph of $f(x)$, or $\frac{x-1}{x^2}$, it is noticeable that this function is not one-to-one.  That is, $f(a_1)=f(a_2)$ where $a_1$ does not equal $a_2$.  This simply makes all of this more complicated.

for $f(b)>f(a)$ to remain true, b and a may be arbitrarily large, meaning xa and yb may be arbitrarily large.  You may see this by viewing a graph of $f(x)$.  From this I say that I simply have no good answer to your question.

Comment: By no good answer to your question, I mean $ax$ and $by$ both reach infinite, making the answer not so helpful in my opinion.  And you are welcomed.  Also, it would be helpful to me if you marked my answer as the one that has satisfied your question.  It is up to you though.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not answer my question, so I don't want to upvote your answer so that it does not give the impression that my question has been answered. But you gave me great insight.

Comment: Your welcome.  Honestly, I don't understand your question then.  :/

Comment: basically I was trying to find values of x and y such that ax and by are as high as they can simultaneously be. As they can't both be maximised and respect the above conditions, (if ax increases bx decreases etc...), I will have to choose to maximise one and the other one has to be the greatest number less than the maximised one. This is the reasoning behind the inequality under 'my approach'

Comment: Hm, from my results, I'd say that $ax$ and $by$ can by any value you want.

Comment: What do you hope to gain from your "personal project?"  If you simply want to become better at math, try answering other people's questions (if you can) and by reading the answers to questions you can't answer.  Try to stick to the questions tagged $algebra/pre-calculus$.

Comment: no, this project has real life applications which I don't want to detail. You're right, my question was not clear, and ax and by may be  any value I want. However note the inequality and the assumption in this part of my argument "My approach to this:

Let's assume I have found an a and a b such that (a∗[c−(c/b)])>=(b∗[c−(c/a)])(a∗[c−(c/b)])>=(b∗[c−(c/a)])

([([(a∗[c−(c/b)])−c]/2)+c]/a)=maximal x"

Comment: That is, if I have found such a and b values that satisfy the inequality above then both ax and by will be greater than zero (then I subtract this 'maximal x' from c to obtain y then multiply this result by y to obtain by) and ax will be larger than by would be if y were calculated as ([([(a∗[c−(c/b)])−c]/2)+c]/a). That's what I meant. I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: The problem is $a$ and $b$ need to be something I can use.  Since the inequality for the two variables is "circular" (they use each other), then I won't be able to answer your question.  Comparing $a$ and $b$ like this is fruitless because I don't know what they are.  If $a$ were exactly this and $b$ were exactly that, then we might be able to go somewhere.  Then this problem would have an exact solution that would be calculable.

Comment: Could you please inject some numbers, then, to demonstrate how you would solve the problem?

Comment: I would detail what these numbers refer to but I'm reluctant to do so as its very useful to me in practice. All I can say is that a and b are always fixed known values.